# How do you rig eyeballs without affecting the rest of the face?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, unreal-engine, manuel-bastioni-lab

I have a human mesh in blender. It's rigged.
I use it in Unreal Engine.
Works fine.
Now I want to have bones to rotate the eyeball(s).

But right now it rotates the eyeball AND part of my face.

So how do I make a bone only affect the eyeball?

All are separate objects (body, eye.r, eye.l).

Sorry, maybe it's due to my lack of correct vocabulary, but I really cannot find a solution. Been trying and googling for days.

Thanks in advance for any hint!
D.D.

Comment: You can edit the weight data directly through weight painting or in edit mode. Bone weights are in a list called "Vertex groups", which can be found in the Object Data panel of the properties window. You can select all the vertices of the face, then remove them from the eye bone vertex groups.

Comment: ok, thanks. but where are the "eye bone vertex groups"? selecting a bone hides my vertex group tab.

Comment: The vertex group data belongs to your mesh object. A mesh that has an armature deform modifier uses its vertex groups to assign vertices to bones. The name of the vertex group must  correspond to the name of the bone. When you parent a mesh to an armature with the "automatic weights" option, vertex groups that match the bone names are created automatically.

Comment: Now I get it! The name is the connection between bones and vertexes. Blender has so many different logics. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workflow for eyes:
First clean any weight paint of your eye bone from your face mesh.
If I understood it correctly face mesh is connected to the eyes? If that's the case then select face in object mode > Edit mode > select eye faces > ctrl + I > H, this will hide everything except eye(s).

Select bone of an eye in pose mode > Ctrl + tab.
Now we have to apply our selection from edit mode.

[image]

Click on the second from the right side icon.

Weight paint whole eye with value 1(red). This creates vertex group with weights for my eye bone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you. 
Ok, so I feel a little stupid right now... Anyway:
My bone has a pose, edit and object mode but no weight paint. Also no vertex groups (tab gets hidden).

But I think you're saying that it is in fact possible to select a bone and connect a vertex group to it? That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Right now my objects are separate objects (body, eye.r, eye.l) for easier selection, but I will try it as joined objects as well.

Comment: You don't paint bones. You create vertex groups with bone's name and paint those, blender lets us automate the process. Select the mesh > weight paint > then double click on the bone. You should see it's name in the bottom left corner of the 3d view.